# math conjugate problem

Tags: math

why is the equation on the left equals the right?
know would I derive it?
[image]

Answer (score 2):

It's just that \$\Gamma_S^* \Gamma_S = \lvert \Gamma_S \rvert^2\$. Thus
$$
\frac{1 - \lvert \Gamma_S \rvert^2}{\lvert 1 - \Gamma_S^*\Gamma_S \rvert^2}
=
\frac{1 - \lvert \Gamma_S \rvert^2}{( 1 - \lvert \Gamma_S \rvert^2 )^2}
=
\frac{1}{1 - \lvert \Gamma_S \rvert^2},
$$
as desired.

Answer (score 1):

Some guidance:

A complex number multiplied by its conjugate is the square of the absolute value.

See it (a+bj)(a-bj)=a^2 - abj + abj - (bj)^2 = a^2 + b^2 = the square of the absolute value of a+bj (only remember that j^2 = -1).